# You should not be able to reply to your own comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

Using the Stack Exchange Android App usage I attempted to "reply to" my own comment with the button. It worked and inserts `@Unihedron` in my message box. This should be fixed, seeing that one cannot ping themselves.

Here are some pictures:

[image: lol][image: lolz]

---

Additional information:
Hardware: SM-G3815 (Samsung Galaxy Express 2)
Software: Android 4.2.2 Build JDQ39.G3815ZHUAMJ6
Running app Stack Exchange version 1.0.48

Comment: This is definitely not a comment just for me to check if I fixed this correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the next app update, version 1.0.50 or higher (hopefully coming out in the next 24 hours) this is fixed. Thanks!